# CameraX error in Android: cannot open camera "0" without camera permission

Tags: android, kotlin

I was developing an app, where I try to implement a Camera App, using CameraX plugin, and I get into the follwing error:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX- Process: es.paytef.paytefmobile, PID: 2747 java.lang.SecurityException: validateClientPermissionsLocked:931: Caller "es.paytef.paytefmobile" (PID 10048, UID 2747) cannot open camera "0" without camera permission at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:733) at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:410) at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraForUid(CameraManager.java:553) at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCamera(CameraManager.java:514) at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera.openCameraDevice(Camera.java:488) at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera.open(Camera.java:144) at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera.addOnlineUseCase(Camera.java:408) at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera$10.run(Camera.java:395) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: validateClientPermissionsLocked:931: Caller "es.paytef.paytefmobile" (PID 10048, UID 2747) cannot open camera "0" without camera permission (code 1) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2027) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1959) at android.hardware.ICameraService$Stub$Proxy.connectDevice(ICameraService.java:339) at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:374)`

Regading the configuration is the following:

build.gralde(app)

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
```

Regarding the use in my activity, is this:

```
class CameraActivity : ListenerCompatActivity(), ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{
companion object {
    const val TAKE_PICTURE = 200
}

private val useCase = Application.useCaseManager.camera
private lateinit var ui: ActivityCameraBinding
private var lensFacing = CameraX.LensFacing.BACK
private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
private var flashMode: FlashMode = FlashMode.OFF
private val filename = "image.png"
private val sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
private val dest = File(sd, filename)

private var resultSent = false
override fun getActivityID(): ActivityID = ActivityID.Camera

override fun isKeepScreenOn() = true

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ui = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(ui.root)
    setListeners()
    bindCamera()
}

private fun setListeners() {
    runOnUiThread {
        ui.btCancelCamera.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO: Check what to do
        }
        // Changes the flash mode when the button is clicked
        ui.btSwitchFlashlight.setOnClickListener {
            val flashMode = imageCapture?.flashMode
            if (flashMode == FlashMode.ON) imageCapture?.flashMode = FlashMode.OFF
            else imageCapture?.flashMode = FlashMode.ON
        }
        ui.viewFinder.setOnClickListener {
            imageCapture?.takePicture(dest,
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener {
                    override fun onError(
                        error: ImageCapture.UseCaseError,
                        message: String, exc: Throwable?
                    ) {
                        Log.e("Image", error.toString())
                        sendResult(
                            ApiCameraResponse(
                                ApiCameraResponse.Result(
                                    success = true,
                                    message = applicationContext.getString(R.string.camera_save_succesfully),
                                    imageContent = Convert.bytesToBase64(dest.readBytes()),
                                    imageType = "image/png",
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    }

                    override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
                        Log.v("Image", "Successfully saved image")
                        sendResult(
                            ApiCameraResponse(
                                ApiCameraResponse.Result(
                                    success = true,
                                    message = applicationContext.getString(R.string.camera_save_succesfully),
                                    imageContent = Convert.bytesToBase64(dest.readBytes()),
                                    imageType = "image/png",
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    }
                })
        }

    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    // Check and request permissions
    if (hasNoPermissions()) {
        checkCameraPermissions(applicationContext)
    }
}

private fun startCameraIntent() {
    /*************************** Camera Intent Start  */
    // Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera
    // application capture an image and return it.
    val request = useCase.getCameraRequest()
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) startActivityForResult(
        intent,
        TAKE_PICTURE
    )


    /*************************** Camera Intent End  */
}

private fun sendCancelResult() {
    sendResult(
        ApiCameraResponse().also { it.setFailed(Messages.CANCEL_BY_USER) }
    )
}

private fun sendResult(result: ApiCameraResponse) {
    logger.info("Sending result = $result")
    resultSent = true
    useCase.setResult(result)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode != TAKE_PICTURE) {
        logger.error("Another request not configured received, request: $requestCode, result: $resultCode")
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
        return
    }

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || data == null) {
        logger.error("Another result received, request: $requestCode, result: $resultCode")
        sendCancelResult()
        return
    }
    try {
        logger.info("Request Code:$requestCode")
        logger.info("Request Code:$requestCode")
        /*********** Load Captured Image And Data Start  */
        //imageFilePath image path which you pass with intent
        val bitmap = intent.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        logger.info("Camera bitmap: $bitmap")
        val byteArray = convertBitmapToByteArray(bitmap)
            ?: throw Exception("NULL camera bitmap captured")
        logger.info("Camera byteArray: $byteArray")
        val result = ApiCameraResponse(
            ApiCameraResponse.Result(
                success = true,
                message = applicationContext.getString(R.string.camera_save_succesfully),
                imageContent = Convert.bytesToBase64(byteArray),
                imageType = "image/png",
            )
        )
        sendResult(result)
        logger.info("image: $bitmap")
        /*********** Load Captured Image And Data End  */
    } catch (ex: Throwable) {
        logger.error("Error capturing camera image", ex)
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
        return
    }
}

/**
 * Bind the Camera to the lifecycle
 */
private fun bindCamera() {
    CameraX.unbindAll()

    // Preview config for the camera
    val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder()
        .setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        .build()

    val preview = Preview(previewConfig)

    // Image capture config which controls the Flash and Lens
    val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
        .setTargetRotation(windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation)
        .setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        .setFlashMode(flashMode)
        .build()

    imageCapture = ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig)

    // Handles the output data of the camera
    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener { previewOutput ->
        // Displays the camera image in our preview view
        ui.viewFinder.setSurfaceTexture(previewOutput.surfaceTexture)
    }

    // Bind the camera to the lifecycle
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, imageCapture, preview)
}

/**
 * Check if the app has all permissions
 */
private fun hasNoPermissions(): Boolean {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

/**
 * Request all permissions
 */
fun checkCameraPermissions(context: Context?) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context!!, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Permission is not granted
        Log.d("checkCameraPermissions", "No Camera Permissions")
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
            100
        )
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when(PermissionChecker.isGranted(
        requestCode,
        grantResults
    )){
        true ->{
            logger.info("permission granted")
        }
        else ->{
            logger.info("Permission not been granted")
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}
```

}

I check in some link that the error is related which the permission okf the app, but in my case I already have all what are need:

```
<!-- MISC PERMISSIONS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="true"
    android:requiredFeature="true"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

If you get into a trouble like this and can bring a solution, take thanks in advance !

Comment: It seems that you are trying to access the camera before the user granted permission to do so.

Comment: I change the code whcic ask for the permission to the onCreate(), instead of called it from onstart(), and I'm still getting the same error. Should I ask when the app just start? IN the main Activity?

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for camera permissions in the `onStart()` method and requesting them if they are missing. You should also handle the result of the permission request in the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method and proceed with camera only if the permission is granted.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    // Check and request permissions
    if (hasNoPermissions()) {
        checkCameraPermissions(applicationContext)
    } else {
        // Permissions already granted, proceed with camera operations
        startCameraIntent()
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when (requestCode) {
        TAKE_PICTURE -> {
            // Check if the permission is granted
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, proceed with camera operations
                startCameraIntent()
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle accordingly
                // For example, show a message to the user or disable camera functionality
                // You can also request the permission again
                Log.d("checkCameraPermissions", "Camera permission denied")
            }
        }

        else -> super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }
}
```